# programm can not find constant in libary fcntl.h in c

Tags: c, header-files, fcntl

I am learning C and somehow my programm can not find a constant defined in a libary. In my understanding S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR shoud be defined in fcntl.h, but I get while trying to compile this error:
... error: 'S_IRUSR' undeclared (first use in this function)
... error: 'S_IWUSR' undeclared (first use in this function)

My programm looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int filedeskriptor;
  char SchreibeTxt [100] = "Hallo getMonth", LeseTxt [100];

  filedeskriptor = open("getMonthTxt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
  if (filedeskriptor == -1){
    printf("Fehler beim Öffnen von mydat \n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (write(filedeskriptor, SchreibeTxt, sizeof(SchreibeTxt)) == -1){
    printf("Fehler beim Schreiben in mydat \n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("In getMonthTxt geschrieben: %s \n", SchreibeTxt);
  close(filedeskriptor);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: According to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html those are defined in "sys/stat.h", not "fcntl.h"

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks. But it's neither creating the file nor getting my 'printf("In getMonthTxt geschrieben: %s \n", SchreibeTxt)'. Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense to have a separate question for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on according to which POSIX-version your compiler and implementation is build up to, because `S_IRUSR` and `S_IWUSR` are only provided inside of `fcntl.h` in POSIX.1-2008 as [Ian Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott) said in the comments.

If your compiler uses a preceding POSIX-version, the macros `S_IRUSR` and `S_IWUSR` are not defined in `fcntl.h` as you can see [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/fcntl.h.html). They are then defined in the header `sys/stat.h`.

Here is a link to the description about the content of the header `sys/stat.h`, where you can find those:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html

---

So if your compiler uses a version predating POSIX.1-2008, add `#include <sys/stat.h>` at the top of your code or otherwise if you don´t need anything from `fcntl.h` replace it with that.

Comment: That's an older version of the POSIX specification you linked to though. POSIX-1.2008 also defines them in `fcntl.h`. You can define a feature test macro to include them such as `#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE`, or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`, or `#define POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`,

Comment: @IanAbbott I changed my answer according to your information. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're missing the headers
<sys/types.h>
<sys/stat.h>

man 2 open states 3 headers for open()